# Which dynamicly added collapsible is opened inside collapsible-set? jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a Collapsible-set (with 5-10 collapsible) and using this code to find wich is opened:

```
$("#mySet").on("collapsibleexpand", function (e) 
{
    var selected = $(".ui-icon-minus").parent().parent().attr("my-data");

// more code...
```

This works when opening a collapsible inside the collapsible-set. Or the current opened is closed before opening a new collapsible. But, if the collapsible is open and clicking on a new collapsible inside my collapsible-set, it fails, and I get the value from the previous opened.

Is there a better way doing this?
Using jQuery mobile 1.4.0

I've also tried this, but then I only get the first collapsible inside my collapsible-set

```
var foo = $("[data-role=collapsible]").attr("my-data");
```

Comment: when do you want to check which collapsible is opened? on closing another one?

Comment: Everytime a collapsible is opened. If my collapsible-set has 10 collabsible I want to know wich one is opened

Comment: you need to bind `collapsibleexpand` to _collapsible_ not _collapsibleset_. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/A5vFz/

Comment: @Omar I add my collapsible dynamic to my collapsible-set. Will try your fiddle!

Comment: @Omar my event work, I just need to get the text for my collapsible. Tried your fiddle, but didn't work dynamicly....

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/A5vFz/

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works, but I changed to .attr("my-data")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind `collapsibleexpand` to *collapsible* not *collapsibleset*. Bind events to *collapsibleset* when you have _collapisbleset_s' within a *collapsibleset*. Moreover, delegate the event to `data-role="collapsible"` or `.ui-collapsible` as you are injecting them dynamically.

Another note, `data-role="collapsible-set"` is deprecated as of jQM 1.4 and will be removed in 1.5, use `data-role="collapsibleset"` instead (just remove *hyphen*).

```
$(document).on("collapsibleexpand","[data-role=collapsible]", function () {
    $(this).doSomething();
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/A5vFz/)**

Comment: Adding data-role solved it! $("#mySet").on("collapsibleexpand", "[data-role=collapsible]", function (e) ... //